# How do I run POCO C++ server pages?

Tags: c++, html, poco-libraries

I'm a beginner in C++ server pages. I have tried **C++ Server Pages** by micronovae, but couldnt connect ODBC it used to give link error "`undefined reference to SQLAllocHandle@12`", I could not resolve it. Similar to micronovae,POCO also  provides C++ Server Pages. so thought of try it. I tried one sample from http://pocoproject.org/docs/PageCompilerUserGuide.html#0 .

What I did is, firstly created a file called TimeHandler.html along with following contents inside it:

```
<%@ page class="TimeHandler" %>
<%!
    #include "Poco/DateTime.h"
    #include "Poco/DateTimeFormatter.h"
    #include "Poco/DateTimeFormat.h"


    using Poco::DateTime;
    using Poco::DateTimeFormatter;
    using Poco::DateTimeFormat;
%>

<%
    DateTime now;
    std::string dt(DateTimeFormatter::format(now, DateTimeFormat::SORTABLE_FORMAT));
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Time Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Time Sample</h1>
<p><%= dt %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I used the commandline Pagecompiler tool, i.e., CPSPCD from command prompt, and it generated following two files,..

1) TimeHandler.cpp

```
#include "TimeHandler.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTMLForm.h"


#line 2 "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\data structures\\vinz\\TimeHandler.html"

    #include "Poco/DateTime.h"
    #include "Poco/DateTimeFormatter.h"
    #include "Poco/DateTimeFormat.h"


    using Poco::DateTime;
    using Poco::DateTimeFormatter;
    using Poco::DateTimeFormat;


void TimeHandler::handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response)
{
   response.setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);
   response.setContentType("text/html");

   Poco::Net::HTMLForm form(request, request.stream());
   std::ostream& responseStream = response.send();
   responseStream << "";
   responseStream << "\n";
   responseStream << "";
   responseStream << "\n";
   responseStream << "\n";
   responseStream << "";
#line 13 "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\data structures\\vinz\\TimeHandler.html"

    DateTime now;
    std::string dt(DateTimeFormatter::format(now, DateTimeFormat::SORTABLE_FORMAT));
   responseStream << "\n";
   responseStream << "<html>\n";
   responseStream << "<head>\n";
   responseStream << "<title>Time Sample</title>\n";
   responseStream << "</head>\n";
   responseStream << "<body>\n";
   responseStream << "<h1>Time Sample</h1>\n";
   responseStream << "<p>";
#line 23 "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\data structures\\vinz\\TimeHandler.html"
   responseStream << ( dt );
   responseStream << "</p>\n";
   responseStream << "</body>\n";
   responseStream << "</html>";
}
```

2) TimeHandler.h

```
#ifndef TimeHandler_INCLUDED
#define TimeHandler_INCLUDED


#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h"


class TimeHandler: public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler
{
public:
   void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response);
};


#endif // TimeHandler_INCLUDED
```

And then I created new project in VS 2010 and added these two files and compiled. There were few issues, but later I updated environment variables and it went on fine. But there is one last error, "....Unresolved symbol _main....".

There was no main inside it.. so how do I run this program??
if not this program, atleast would someone give an overview as to **how to embed C++ code inside html, compile and run it..!**

Comment: for info, also look at [klone](http://www.koanlogic.com/klone/), google [Native Client](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient); Not that I recommend doing websites in C++, but just showing the other options

Comment: hi sehe, Thanks for the quick reply. Native client is however not what i'm looking at, because in NativeClient C++ code is executed by the browser (just like javascript). what i want is somewhat similar to php or asp (server-side scripting).

"klone" seems to fit perfect, but its not free (1950 EUR !). Any similar ones for free-license?

Comment: its okay. Anyway thank you for those links, i was not aware of it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The samples you show only create the individual page (handler) implementation.

You need to add an actual [HTTPServer](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPServer.html) to serve that page.

See: http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPServer.html

There is a sample in the sources download under

```
 poco-1.4.2p1.zip\poco-1.4.2p1\Net\samples\HTTPTimeServer
```

You should be able to get something working from there